# Define private array inside es6 class on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I'm just trying to do define a private array as a property of a class but I'm not able to do it.

Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

```
 class Cart {
      #customerUsername;
      #products[];

     constructor(customerUsername) {
         this.#customerUsername = customerUsername;
         
     }
     
     setCustomerUsername(customerUsername) {
         if(customerUsername) {
             this.customerUsername=customerUsername;
         } else {
             throw Error('Missing customer username');
         }
     }
     
     addProduct(product) {
         if(product) {
             this.products.push(product);
         } else {
             throw Error('Missing product');
         }
     }

 }
```

But seems like define something like #products[] is not a valid declaration.

Any idea of how can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: When you declare a variable, you don't have to specify what it holds. So you don't need `[]`, just use `#products`. Then do `this.#products = []` in the constructor.

Comment: Why _would_ that be a valid declaration? You're just trying to jam the value into the name, you need a `=` somewhere.

Comment: Or potentially just `#products = []` _outside_ the constructor, depending on your environment/transpilation.

Comment: There are two syntax errors ... 1) the private field can be declared and assigned within the class body like ... `#products = [];` 2) the prototypal `addProduct` method has to access and push into the private products array like this ... `this.#products.push(product);` (the privacy hash was/is missing). If fixed like suggested the example code will run as intended by the OP.